# openapi-generator-cli: readonly properties

Tags: openapi-generator-cli

I am trying to generate the code automatically using the aspnetcore server generator (`npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g aspnetcore ...`).

The problem occurs with the readonly properties: they are not marked readonly in the API.

What about generate the properties with a private setter and add a public "Set"-Method to set them ?

For example if the "Name" property is marked readonly in the yml-file:

[image]
the code generated for the property could be:

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
...
public void SetName(string value) { Name = value; }
```

instead of only:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is your question? That's not a read-only property. A read-only property would be `public string Name { get; }`, and only settable via a default value, or the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by readonly. If your server sends back data, it does not get to decide what is done with that data. If your server receives data (for example for an update) it should simply not accept fields that you don't want updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement OpenAPI readOnly and writeOnly with Swashbuckle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992487/how-to-implement-openapi-readonly-and-writeonly-with-swashbuckle)

Comment: In the yml-file the property is defined as readonly:
properties:
        Name:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
          description: Descriptive name of the project
the code generated for the property is:
        public string Uri { get; set; }
in browser, if you click on schemas, the property is not marked as readonly. To get a readonly property the code generated should be:
         public string Uri { get; private set; }

Comment: I am using "npx openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g .... " to generate the c# solution automatically

Comment: Yeah, so that's a different question altogether! How did you expect us to guess that from your first post? Please read the help section of Stack Overflow on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `openapi-generator` is currently not supporting OAS 3.0's `readOnly`/`writeOnly` as shown in [this (2.5 yo) open request/issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4190). It also doesn't seem to be planned for any release yet.

You can "like" the issue on github to give it more attention. But somebody needs to do the work, or you need to do it yourself.

Until it's implemented, you need to edit the files after generation.